# Compare two strings in JS and return the remainder of the new string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I am currently building a "type it out" style plugin to improve my skills with Javascript & jQuery. Everything is working as expected so far. However, I am having trouble implementing a function to store the duplicates of words in strings that have the same words.

For instance, if I pass the plugin an array like `['Our Community', 'Our Family', Our Friends']` I would like to only spell out the words that are not being repeated.

This is the following function I am using to erase the word:

```
function clearString(el, cb) {

    var length;

    el.html(function(_, html) {

        length = html.length;
        return html.substr(0, length - 1);
    });

    if(length > 1) {

        setTimeout(function () {

            clearString(el, cb);
        }, humanize/2);

    } else {

        cb();
    }
}
```

I tried adding in the following when I am changing the html to check for similarities with no luck:

```
if( index !== 0 ) {
    var string1 = strings[index],
        string2 = strings[index - 1];

    if( string1.indexof(string2) !== -1 ) {
        // yes it does
            cb();
    }
}
```

Basically what I want is, with my example in the beginning, if I had a string "Our Community" and the next one was "Our family"; I want to check for that "Our" piece so I can stop erasing and use the callback to go back and start writing the next string... Also, my problem is... Do I need to save where this value occurs, then use something like `substr()` to remove only a certain piece of the string?

I've been reading around a lot the past two days, on here and other sites trying to figure out the best way to implement this functionality. Any help/direction is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good use of a regular expression should help in this task. Divide on whitespace boundaries and then use matched index to determine if other strings match. A usage of replace(match_Array[my_index],'') should allow you to replace the matched text with no characters.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp